# How do I append code to a function in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

In my project, I am used a lot of classes and methods. Project is working fine. But now I need a performance optimization. I want a logging option for track execution time of each method. Changing each function code is not good.

So my question is, can I append/inject some code block to every method, without touch the existing code; I need a log entry before and after execution of a method with time.

Please do not recommend any third party tools.

Comment: Without third party, AOP is not supported. Take a look at postsharp.net

Comment: are you working with winforms ?

Comment: What's wrong with Visual Studio? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: It is ASP.Net Project

Comment: I would agree with  ta.speot.is with an addition: Visual Studio 2015 CTP's . take a look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/08/18/perftips-performance-information-at-a-glance-while-debugging-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Is your application using an IoC container?

Comment: @ta.speot.is : I am working on VS 2010 Professional.There is no Performance Profiler.

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET and not using a profiler like ANTS or Visual Studio, look at Glimpse http://getglimpse.com/

Comment: I can suggest reading this article: [CLR Injection: Runtime Method Replacer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer)